# OnListItemClick is not firing

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to set up an OnItemClickListener for a ListView that was created inside of the main activity (extending Activity). The following code is not firing. Why isn't the onItemClick running?

Main.java

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    List<Title> titleList;
    ListView lv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // set list view
        setContentView(R.layout.listview);
        setTitle("TITLE");

        // Create Parser for raw/countries.xml
        TitleParser titleParser = new TitleParser();
        InputStream inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.titles);

        // Parse the input stream
        titleParser.parse(inputStream);

        // Get Titles
        titleList = titleParser.getList();

        // Create a customized ArrayAdapter
        TitleArrayAdapter adapter = new TitleArrayAdapter(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.title_listitem, titleList);

        // Get reference to ListView holder
        lv = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.titleLV);

        // Set the ListView adapter
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        // on list item click
        AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {
                Title title = (Title) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                try{
                    Class<?> challengeClass = Class.forName("com.glvangorp.app.TITLECHALLENGE");
                    Intent challengeIntent = new Intent(Main.this, challengeClass);
                    challengeIntent.putExtra("challenge", title.challenge);
                    challengeIntent.putExtra("title", title.resourceId);
                    startActivity(challengeIntent);
                } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
                    Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(listener);        
    }
}
```

listview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/titleLV"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: add some line in method to print some word if method is working or not. Or post your full code of activity. Are you getting any exception ?

Comment: post the xml layout code in which you have taken ListView.

Comment: Put breakpoint in inside the onItemClick and debug your code..

Comment: I tried putting the breakpoint inside of onItemClick but it never gets to it. I have it on my phone now and it runs without force closing but I cannot "click" on an item

Answer (score 0):

one reason one not calling is the list item has been set to clickable false. or on the list item you have set some click or touch listener with return true ( make it to return false if you have written).

Comment: I just added <ListView android:clickable="false"/>. no change. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is getting called but you are just getting an ClassNotFoundException thus, you don't know if it doing anything in the OnItemClick ... Why don't you put a `Log.d("TAG", e.getMessage);` inside the

> catch clause.

Comment: I added your suggested line, but nothing is being written to the LogCat when I run the app.

Comment: It's never even getting to the onitemclick method